# Django & Haystack: Beautify the search url

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I have a problem with Django and Haystack. I'm trying to beautify the url (example.com/search/?q=hey in example/search/hey/) as follows:

```
def go(request):
    """
    Search > Beautify
    """
    search_query = request.GET.get('q', None)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('search.views.root', kwargs={
        'search_query': search_query,
    }))

def root(request, search_query):
    """
    Search > Root
    """

    form = HaystackSearchForm(request.GET)
    tutorials = form.search()

    return render(request, 'search/search_root.html', {
        'search_query' : search_query,
        'tutorials' : tutorials,
    })
```

The problem is that it doesn't work because the request for the go function is not the same than the root function. I want to find a way to pass the appropriate request to the HaystackForm (which mean with the query).

Comment: You mean uglify? That isn't a proper RESTful search URL.

Comment: Do you prefer foo.com/search?var=hey than foo.com/search/hey/ ? I thought it was better to do the second ?

Comment: It's best to choose a right tool for a job. `foo.com/bar/hey/` style URLs are great if they are paths to proper resources on your server, for example posts or user profiles. But when it comes to user queries you should stick with standard GET parameters.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Thank you very much.